# how to search multiple domain extensions using dns_get_record()

Tags: php, dns, get, record

I am trying to verify multiple domain names or extensions using `dns_get_record()`.

what I have tried to achieve is this.

this will only check for single domain or extension.

```
$name_domain = trim($_POST['domain_name']).$_POST['suffix'];
$response = @dns_get_record($name_domain, DNS_ALL);
if(empty($response)){
            $msg = "<h2 style='color:green;' >Domain $name_domain is available.</h2>";
}else if(!empty($response)){
            $msg = "<h2 style='color:red;'>Domain $name_domain has taken.</h2>";
}
echo $msg;
```

and this is I tried to check for multiple domain names if they are available or not.

I also want to show that domain names to echo if they are available like parwest.com, parwest.org, parwest.net if this all are available it should be echo as I tried to do.

else if these are not available or any of from this is not available then that also echo as
I showed.

```
$name_domain = trim($_POST['domain_name']).$_POST['suffix'];
$domains = array( trim($_POST['domain_name']).'.com', trim($_POST['domain_name']).'.net' ,trim($_POST['domain_name']).'.org',);

$response = @dns_get_record(implode(' ',$domains), DNS_ALL);
if(empty($response)){
            $msg = "<h2 style='color:green;' >Domain ".implode('<br>', $domains)." is available.</h2>";
}else if(!empty($response)){
            $msg = "<h2 style='color:red;'>Domain ".implode('<br>', $domains)." has taken.</h2>";
}
```

but its not working. :(

any idea how can I do this?

Comment: dns_get_record expects hostaname to be a string, you are tying to parse it an array, you instead need to loop through your array parseing one at a time.

Comment: any examples can you show regarding my this code?

Comment: just add a `foreach()` loop

Comment: I really don't have idea how to do this, can you give me example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$name_domain = trim($_POST['domain_name']).$_POST['suffix'];
$domains = array( trim($_POST['domain_name']).'.com', trim($_POST['domain_name']).'.net' ,trim($_POST['domain_name']).'.org',);

$msg='';
foreach($domains as $d){

$response = @dns_get_record($d, DNS_ALL);
if(empty($response)){
            $msg .= "<h2 style='color:green;' >Domain $d is available.</h2>";
}else if(!empty($response)){
            $msg .= "<h2 style='color:red;'>Domain $d has taken.</h2>";
}

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I really appreciate your this answer,

But I am getting this error `Notice: Undefined variable: msg in`